# Showing that $\{ \frac{1}{n } \}_{n \in \mathbb{N} }$ has only one accumulation point: $a=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I'm reading in my textbook about accumulation points for sequences. There is an example about $a_n = 1/n$ which I do not understand. But let me first give you the definition of an acc. pt. (from the textbook):

**$a$ is an accumulation point for the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ if and if only $\forall \varepsilon>0 \forall N \in \mathbb{N} \exists n \geq N: \quad\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon$**

I will like to show that $a_n = 1/n$ has only $a=0$ as an acc. pt. My strategy is to first show that $a=0$ is and accumulation point. This I'm comfortable with (for this example). **But what is the general strategy for showing that a point is an acc. pt.?**

I have also a hard time showing that $a_n=1/n$ does not have other accumulation points than $a=0$. I thinking that I will negate the definition of an accumulation point. But I'm not quit sure how to negate this expression. I do not know whether it is

$$ \exists \varepsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \geq N: \quad\left|a_{n}-a\right| \geq \varepsilon$$

or

$$ \exists \varepsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \color{red}{<} N: \quad\left|a_{n}-a\right| \geq \varepsilon$$

**Is this the general strategy for showing that $a$ is NOT an acc. pt.?**

PS: I was also thinking about whether one could use that the set $\{ n : |a_n-a| < \varepsilon \}$ if finite if $a$ is not an acc. pt.?

Kind regards,

Comment: @rae306 Erm, no - $\forall N\exists n>N$ makes this the definition of an accumulation point

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, exactly. Def. of a limit is $\forall \varepsilon>0 \exists N \in \mathbb{N} \forall n \geq N: \quad\left|a_{n}-a\right|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that there will be a general strategy to show the a point is an accumulation point.  To show that a point is not accumulation point it might be helpful to read out loud what an accumulation point $a$ of a sequence $(a_n)$ mean: *every neighbourhood of $a$ contains infinitely many members of the sequence $(a_n)$.*  From here it should be easy to see that a (strict) monotonous sequence possesses at most one accumulation point: Just assume that there were two of them.  Then separate them.

Comment: You posted two answers. You might want to delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

A sequence has an accumulation point $a$ if and only if there exists a subsequence that converges to $a$. Since $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} = 0,$$
every convergent subsequence necessarily converges to $0$. So $0$ is the only accumulation point.

This is the general strategy if you have a convergent sequence. However, there exist sequences with just one accumulation point which is not the limit, e.g.
$$a_n = \cases{ \frac{1}{n} \quad  n \text{ even} \\  n \quad \,n \text{ odd}}$$
in which case you have to be more careful.

Comment: Thanks! But at this point I do not know anything about subsequences so I have to only use the definition. I will appreciate it if you answered my questions.